# Continuum formulation of the Kitaev chain

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, topological-phase

In Kitaev's seminal paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0010440), the Kitaev chain is described in a lattice formulation. On the other hand, many of the original papers on the the related semiconductor-superconductor nanowire system present a continuum formulation of their models instead (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1145 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.4033, for example).

I would like to find a source which describes the Kitaev model in the continuum formulation. In particular I am also looking for the continuum description of the wavefunction of the Majorna Bound States of this system. Has this been done in the literature? What would be good places to look at?